# CloudBlobDirectory.ListBlobs not returning blobs that have been recently uploaded

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Using the Azure Storage Client Library, I make several calls to upload blobs using the synchronous version of `CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream`.

If I do a call to `CloudBlobDirectory.ListBlobs` within a few seconds of the upload, it will be missing some of the files.

**After some time passes, ListBlobs will show all the files.**

My understanding is that when you use `CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream`, the file should be fully done uploading when this call returns, and should show up in `CloudBlobDirectory.ListBlobs`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the list call happening with the same connection context? Are you using SAS at all?

Comment: Well we are storing the reference to the CloudBlobContainer in a static property in an ASP.net application.  However we're on azure, so I'm not sure having the same connection context is assured across the role instances.  We are authenticating through a connection string as opposed to SAS